# Set asp:LinkButton text in markup

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

How would it be possible to set text of ASP.NET LinkButton like below:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton_Select" runat="server" Text='
<p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Start")%></p>&nbsp;
<p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "End")%></p>
'/>
```

Comment: What's the question?  Are you having a problem with that code??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton_Select" runat="server" Text='<%# "<p>"+ DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Start")+"</p>&nbsp;<p>"+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "End")+"</p>"%>'/>
```

Comment: But a <p> tag inside an <a> tag is still invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do the below:

```
<p><asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton_Select" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Start")%>'/><p>
<p><asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton_Select2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "End")%>'/><p>
```

Comment: This is also good as well. but I prefer to use only one linkButton.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton_Select" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("<p>{0}</p>&nbsp;<p>{1}</p>",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Start"),DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "End")) %>'/>
```

Comment: Thanks. The above answer is simpler!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will fail because, on a `runat="server` tag, each attribute has to either be *completely* a `'<%# %>'` section, or not at all. You can't use `<%# %>` for part of it and plain text for the rest. @StrouMfios showed the way around that using string.Format, but there's another issue - when converted to HTML, you'd end up with an `<a>` tag containing `<p>` tags, which is illegal. If splitting it up into two separate linkbuttons doesn't work for you, the only other way you could do it *legally* is by using `<span>` tags styled to be display:block with extra spacing.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer which is the most simple:

Text='<%# "

"+ Eval("Start") + "

" +  Eval("End")+"

"

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, set the value of attribute text in the page load.

Example:

**yourpage.aspx**

```
<asp:Button ID="yourButtonId" runat="server" OnClick="StartEvent" />
```

**yourpage.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set Text asp:Button
    yourButtonId.Text = "Your text";
}
```